# How to improve accuracy of accelerometer and compass sensors?

Tags: android, accelerometer, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

i am creating an augmented reality app that simply visualices a textview when the phone is facing a Point of Interest (wich gps position is stored on the phone). The textview is painted on the point of interest location in the screen.

It works ok, the problem is that compass and accelerometer are very "variant", and the textview is constantly moving up and down left and right because the innacuracy of the sensors.

there is a way to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742740/android-accelerometer-filtering

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our problem is same. I also had same problem when I create simple augmented reality project. The solution is to use [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) or moving average function. I recommend exponential smoothing because it only need to store one previous values. Sample implementation is available below :

```
private float[] exponentialSmoothing( float[] input, float[] output, float alpha ) {
        if ( output == null ) 
            return input;
        for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
             output[i] = output[i] + alpha * (input[i] - output[i]);
        }
        return output;
}
```

Alpha is smoothing factor (0<= alpha <=1). If you set alpha = 1, the output will be same as the input (no smoothing at all). If you set alpha = 0, the output will never change. To remove noise, you can simply smoothening accelerometer and magnetometer values.

In my case, I use accelerometer alpha value = 0.2 and magnetometer alpha value = 0.5. The object will be more stable and the movement is quite nice.

Comment: May I ask, this input[i] are the x,y,z values of accelerometer?

Comment: @DawoodAwan No, they input[] are the "event.values" parameter of the "onSensorChanged" event.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at low-pass filters for you orientation data or sensor fusion if you want to a step further.

Good Luck with your app.

JQCorreia

Comment: Hi, please can you explain it a little more? i dont understand what are you talking about, but sounds nice

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911900/android-remove-gravity-from-accelerometer-readings/6912977#6912977 and the links inside.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a simple trick. This will delay your results a bit but they surly avoid the inaccuracy of the compass and accelerometer.

Create a history of the last `N` values (so save the value to an array, increment index, when you reach `N` start with zero again). Then you simply use the arithmetic average of the stored values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this proposal, i will try it. Bytheway, to compare your code, did you have the code example for doing that please?

Comment: I did it for iPhone long time ago so unfortunately no  ;-) But it's quite simple. You just build the sum of the array, divide by `N` and use this value instead the direct value you get from compass or accelerometer.

Comment: thanks, i test it and it works a little, but the textview is still moving to all directions some pixels :/

Comment: You will never find the perfect value, because your compass and accelerometer is far from perfect. You can increase `N` and choose it's value where you're satisfied with the delay/view jump ratio.

Comment: Note that what you are doing is a low-pass filter of the input signal.

Comment: I see, your right. I just didn't consider to use a weight and kept it linear. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of gyroscope sensor readings can give a huge improvement in the stability of the final estimation of the orientation.
Have a look at the [steady compass](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.netpatia.android.filteredcompass) application if your device has a gyroscope, or just have a look at the video if you do not have a gyroscope.

The integration of gyroscope can be done in a rather simple way using a *complementary filter*.